# kazam application records a black box screen when I open the video from another device

Tags: linux-mint, kde

In this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176902/screencast-only-records-a-black-box) It showed that this has to do with wayland session

In my case when I run the provided command ( **echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE** ) it gives  the output **x11** and not wayland which is not the case in the other answers also I use kde plasma and not gdm3 on linux mint 20 so the answers solution for modifying /etc/gdm3/custom.conf didn't work for me the videos play just as it supposed to be when I run them on the same device I recorded them but trying to share them over whatsapp or something or moving them to my smartphone It just gives a black screen.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654906/439939) saved my day! I did not think that VLC is the issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try opening the video with other app.

I had the same issue and it turned out to be VLC problem with playing mp4 video.

You can also save in different format.

Comment: Same. Fixed by disabling Hardware acceleration in VLC: Tools -> Preferences -> Input/Codecs/Hardwale-accelerated decoding = Disable